# Does Azure AD B2C login page send the credentials in clear text?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect, saml

Does Azure AD B2C login page send the credentials in clear text over the network or does it encrypt the credentials for instance with a public key before sending them over the network?

The idea is to understand if there is a way to prevent clear text credentials over the network. In case of something leaks, it is not the real password.

The follow up question is, what about OpenID Connect and SAML do they support a feature that would help avoid clear text passwords from travelling over the network?

Comment: When you say "the network", which network? OpenID Connect and SAML both support not sending passwords via clear text in that neither have anything to do with passwords. They're both protocols for a client (e.g. a web app) to request a user be authenticated using a remote system and for that remote system to return something (e.g. JWT) securely to indicate the user is authenticated. How the user authenticated is out of scope for OpenID Connect & SAML, it may be a password it may be something else entirely.

Comment: When I say the network I'm referring to network where the data is going to travel. for instance you request azure b2c login page. then you have to put the credentials. when you put the credentials they are inserted in clear text. then these credentials have to travel from the browser to the azure b2c servers in order to get the auth token. the space in between the browser and the azure b2c would be the network(s). and I'm asking if the credentials travel in clear text or with some encryption

Comment: Dave D, Thanks for Clarifying the OpenId Connect and the SAML portion of the question by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the password is set in the clear.

It's encrypted at the transport layer (https). It won't allow connections over http.

Both SAML and OIDC allow encrypted tokens to be returned to the app.